# xeCJK display blank characters when using custom font

Tags: xetex, fontspec, xecjk

I'm using xeLatex and the package `xeCJK` to display japanese characters. When i'm using the `SimSun` font it works perfectly. But when I'm using my custom font nothing displays.

The font I want to use is `Togalite` and I have the `togalite-regular.otf` file. I installed the font with the Windows font preview.

Here is my preamble :

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont{Togalite}
% I also tried
% \setCJKmainfont{トガリテ regular}
% \setCJKmainfont{togalite-regular.otf}
```

Here is the output of `fc-list | Select-String -Pattern "togalite"`

`C:/Users/louisld/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts/togalite-regular.otf: Togalite,繝医ぎ繝ｪ繝・Togalite regular,繝医ぎ繝ｪ繝・regular:style=regular`

I also put the `togalite-regular.otf` file in the same folder as my tex file.

The fontspec logs :

```
Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Togalite/BI" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Togalite/B" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Togalite/I" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Font family 'Togalite(0)' created for font 'Togalite'
(fontspec)             with options [Script={CJK}].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Togalite/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:
```

Comment: don't use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with xetex. (I deleted my initial comment as that line made me think you were using pdftex)

Comment: I removed the fontenc package but nothing changed.

Comment: Check the log file if it reports a missing char.

Comment: I edit my post with the logs. I don't know if there is anything wrong.

Comment: Have you tried open the PDF in another viewer? On my MiKTeX installation, the PDF viewer of TeXworks displays nothing, but Adobe Acrobat Reader displays `togalite-regular.otf` content correctly. See also https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/214

Comment: A more concise MWE `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{togalite-regular.otf}

\begin{document}
M+派生：フランス語で平等を意味する“égalitéリガリテ”と“尖る”という言葉から“トガリテ（togalité）”と名づけたフォント
\end{document}`

Comment: You are right, when I display the pdf in Adobe reader the font works well. Thank you.